# When selecting Special Operations for Term 2 during character creation, what Rank should I be noting?

Tags: character-creation, twilight-2000, twilight-2000-4.0

I am working through character creation using the Life Path Method for Twilight 2000 v4 (2021 - from Free League).  Term 1 is simple enough, with a lot of options.

I want to move into Special Operations for Term 2.  I meet all the noted requirements (attributes all at the correct levels and 1 term in Combat Arms).  I did get a promotion, but that only puts me at PFC.  Starting Rank for Special Operations, however, is Sergeant.

**Do I automatically become a Sergeant when selecting Special Operations for Term 2?**  Or do I have to spend 2 more terms in Combat Arms (at least, assuming promotions) to achieve that rank before I can select that as an option?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question! I don't have an answer, but I've been trying to remember the name of this game for decades.

Answer (score 1):

Your character gets promoted to Sergeant when you select Special Operations.

The example on page 39 of the Player's Manual has a chargen example which does exactly that. Section 5 says:

> Clark enters Special Operations. He is promoted to Sergeant, increases Ranged Combat to C and gets Survival D.

So every time you pick a new career path you'll get promoted to whatever rank the 'starting rank' is on the table on page 32.